# Laravel 5.6 Ajax autocomplete from an api

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have an external API which returns a list of products and prices.  I cant to store this data in the database and I am not interested in displaying the entire list due to some privacy issues.  Instead, I would like show a subset of the list with live search / autocomplete.   How do I go about it?

Answer (score -1):

This is more of a frontend related thing, give [jQuery UI Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) a try.